# SpringBoot + Maven connects and create database schema

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

It's there anyway to create a springboot application that whent it runs for the first time, connect to mysql, and creates the database schema if it do not exists?

I'm using this configuration:

@Configuration

public class DataConfiguration {

```
@Bean

public DataSource dataSource(){

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");

    dataSource.setUsername("root");

    dataSource.setPassword("root");

    return dataSource;

}


@Bean

public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

    adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);

    return adapter;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
Spring boot already has an integration with Flyway and Liquidbase.

For example, Flyway allows creating the schema and running a series of database migrations upon the first run.

If the migrations are already done, flyway won't change the database schema.
This tool is really powerful and you can configure it to run when the spring boot application starts.

Check [This document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) for more information about spring boot integration with database related tools